# Handling an escaped quote character in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a string (varchar) in MySQL and want to handle `"` and `\"` as different characters. How can I do that?

Example:

```
select locate('"', '\"Easy\" "');
```

Answer is 1, I want the result 10.

Comment: Read your own question, and tell me seriously did you understood?

Comment: Please elaborate more before downvoting commences ..

Comment: Why does the string contain both quoted and unquoted `"`s? That looks like a bad idea.

Comment: Seems to me that OP basically wants something like `(?<!\)"` (or possibly escaped - `(?<!\\)"`) for anyone that knows regex, but I don't know about a regex MySQL locate.

Answer (score 2):

`\"` is not a character - it is the escape sequence for `"` in a string - and `\\\"` is the escape sequence for the **character sequence** `\"`.

If you want to search for the **character sequence** `"` but not `\"`, A `REGEXP` will give you at least the answer **if** it is in there:

```
SELECT '\\\"Easy\\\" \"' REGEXP '[^\\]\"'; -- gives 1
SELECT '\\\"Easy\\\" x' REGEXP '[^\\]\"'; -- gives 0
```

**Edit**

Just to clear out confusion about the escaping of quotes:

- inside **single** quotes, the escaping of double quotes is optional: `'\"'` is the same as `'"'`
- inside **double** quotes, the escaping of single quotes is optional: `"\'"` is the same as `"'"`

It is heavily recommended to always use escaping, even if it is optional.

**Edit 2**

@Dukeling pointed out, that I forgot the edge case of a string starting with `"`. This fixes it:

```
SELECT '\\\"Easy\\\" x' REGEXP '([^\\]|^)\"'; --gives 0
SELECT '\\\"Easy\\\" \"' REGEXP '([^\\]|^)\"'; --gives 1
SELECT 'x \\\"Easy\\\"' REGEXP '([^\\]|^)\"'; --gives 0
SELECT '\" \\\"Easy\\\"' REGEXP '([^\\]|^)\"'; --gives 1
```

Comment: See my edit for this!

Comment: Why is it recommended to escape `"` in single quotes?

Comment: @Dukeling Good catch! See my second edit.

Comment: @meze: To reduce the likelyhood of error. Make the string independent of the quoting applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Although you use single qotes as delimiters, the double quotes are still escaped and viewed as just double quotes. If you actually have the backslash saved in the field, you can simulate it as this:</del>

<del>SELECT LOCATE('"', '\"Easy\" "');</del>

EDIT: Forgot that \" should not be matched. Use regexp, as Eugen suggests.

Comment: I'm not sure what this was supposed to do, but [it doesn't seem to change much](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/13178). Still prints (what is now) 2 instead of (what will know be) 12.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that the \" sequence should not be matched. As Eugen points out, regexp is the way to go here.